# How do I write a custom query as a Root in JPA Criteria query API?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

My query is :

```
select * from tbl1 t1,
(select max(modified_datetime),id as ID ,status from 
 tbl2 group by modified_datetime,ID,status) t2 
where 
t1.ID=t2.ID;
```

How do I achieve this ?

Please help!

Comment: You should provide us your entities and code you have tried. What problems did you have with it?

Answer (score 0):

With no code provided I assume you have all configuration done. Below is the solution for you.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from tbl1 t1,(select max(modified_datetime),id as ID ,status from tbl2 group by modified_datetime,ID,status) t2 where t1.ID=t2.ID;")
    ReturnType methodName(@Param("paramsHereIfAny") String paramsHereIfAny);
```

---

Edited after comments

```
//some parameters to your method
        String param1 = "1";
        String paramNull = null;

        CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery cq = qb.createQuery();
        Root<A> customer = cq.from(A.class);

        //Constructing list of parameters
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        //Adding predicates in case of parameter not being null
        if (param1 != null) {
            predicates.add(
                    qb.equal(customer.get("someAttribute"), param1));
        }
        if (paramNull != null) {
            predicates.add(
                    qb.equal(customer.get("someOtherAttribute"), paramNull));
        }
        //query itself
        cq.select(customer)
                .where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
        //execute query and do something with result
        em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

---

Take a look at this site [JPA Criteria API](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria). There are plenty of examples.

Comment: But this is not using JPA Criteria API as requested

Comment: You need to post your code then. Please add relevant details

Comment: I am editing my answer with basic criteria example  but if it doesn't satisfy your need. Post adequate details.